# .Net core async method thread safety

Tags: c#, .net-core

Im trying to create sample Web Api project in .Net Core 3.1, which helps to sell online theatre tickets. So i added controller method which returns last ticket number for current client:

```
namespace MyTestWebAPI1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class TicketController : Controller
    {
        private ILogger<TicketController> _logger;
        private DataContext _context;
        public TicketController(ILogger<TicketController> logger, DataContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<string> GetTicketNumber()
        {
            var ticketNumber = string.Empty;
            using (var cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {
                bool wasOpen = cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open;
                if (!wasOpen) cmd.Connection.Open();
                try
                {
                    //Calling database scalar function:
                    cmd.CommandText = $"select Get_Next_Ticket_Number() from dual";
                    var scalarResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    ticketNumber == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : (string)scalarResult;                    
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (!wasOpen) cmd.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
          //Here has other code segment which linked to save client data to database, 
          //for this i simpley replacing it with Task.Delay() for sample ))
            await Task.Delay(20000); 
            return ticketNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

How i can do this method thread safe, those. it doesn't have return one ticket data to several clients

Comment: What does Get_Next_Ticket_Number do? Implement a Sequence: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm

Comment: Get_Next_Ticket_Number  database function returns last ticket hash string data (ticket id), by using this string data i will generate QR code for ticket

Comment: If you a trying to create an identity field `Ticket_Number` that you manually increment, then this is likely the wrong approach. Databases have better ways of dealing with this

Comment: I now in Oracle has autoincrement, now i have problem if at the same time comes two or more client request then they interfere with each other

Comment: you could leverage lock https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement. Make sure you read & implement it correctly, in one of my project that lock still got through and I still see cases where there double number from 2 member submitted same time. It could be my incorrect implementation.

Comment: how i may implement "lock" in .Net Core 3.1?

Comment: I leave that to others for the correct implementation in .Net core.

Comment: In this case what i can use for right solution?

Comment: There are lock and mutex, lock is the correct way if your application on the same APP Domain. Some others thing will be using identity column in database.

Comment: If at all possible, you don't do what you are trying to do. If you need a pre-generated id, create a record that is in a pre-generated state with the database incremented id and use its id. Doing it any other way is futile at best, or just bad design

Comment: my first impression on this is use a lock mechanism. yes from the comment by @Ariwibawa , you can use mutex..

Comment: btw, best maybe don't use threading on your method.. it's a bit complex to use threading in an asynchronous  method..

Comment: As far as I understand your problem, changing the method from `async Task<string>` to a non async one with just `string` would not resolve the concurrency problem. Multiple clients can still call the controller at the same time and they run concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty much "buying a dog and barking yourself"

- Make the database generate the ticket number on insert (either an auto incrementing number or a Guid)
- insert a record (create a new Ticket entity without a ticket number) and save it
- EF will retrieve the database generated values and put them into the entity (probably by doing INSERT INTO .. RETURNING .. but we don't really care; it's the EF providers problem, not ours)
- Use the updated details to generate a QR code
- All this happens as part of the same controller method; the user is logged in, you know who they are, you insert the ticket associated with their account so it can be retrieved at any time later after you find out who they are (they log in)

All this "get a connection, run an sql that finds out the previously inserted record, mutex and lock it so that only one sql can run at a time blah blah" is just crackers; you might as well not use EF if you're going to go down that rabbit hole.

This is all already handled for you, as is thread management and concurrent requests, if you do it the way it was intended to be used; the more you subvert it, the more you'll end up piling on bodge after hack and making life very hard work

Comment: ok, one case for your answer,
for example Get_Next_Ticket_Number db function  returned last ticketnumber 15, and begin running next lines of code (insertion clinet data to database,  etc.), but if until to insertion last selling ticket data to db, next client request data came and get same ticket number, after this  what happens ?

Comment: @MansurKurtov use db transactions?

Comment: @mansurkurtov I think you didn't understand my answer at all. Throw your Get_Next_Ticket_Number function away. It's the root cause of all your problems and misunderstandings. Ticket numbers should be generated by db on inserting a ticket, not as something you do first to get the value to insert. It's a `Select max(id) + 1` which is pure crap. If you let the db manage the insert and generate of ticket number via built in identity/autoinc it will never, ever conflict. You're still trying to find workarounds for problems you're causing that wouldn't exist if you did it the way you're supposed to

Comment: @galdin not helpful

Comment: @CaiusJard you're right. totally missed the `Get_Next_Ticket_Number()` bit

Answer (score -1):

Set index od database column and make them unique. U will get exceptions if two client, in the same time call GetTicketNumber.

Comment: This doesn't help either. Do you really think the busiest websites in the world use this approach to make sure every visitor has some unique X "just keep re-running `select max(id)+1` until you succeed in getting a record inserted"?

Comment: Agree, it's not the best solution, but a select query to get the possible value and put it back in is also the wrong approach.
Why not just insert 'ticket' to database and return the autogenerated number/id (your answer)?  
Index is better then nothing .

Comment: @CaiusJard thinking he is best of the best, but i didn't got right answer for my question yet, for his reputation i got -1 point for my question ((